# 'limit' vs 'limitation'

Tags: differences

What are the similarities and differences? I already tried the OED, but [its richness (ie plenitude) of information can overwhelm me, a novice.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6693/50720)

I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but does etymology help reveal anything? [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=limit&searchmode=none) (and also OED) shows that **limit**'s etymology differs (slightly) from **limitation**'s.

Comment: Try say AHDEL and Collins.

Comment: limits are inherent, limitations are imposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search Google Books for

**merriam webster synonym dictionary limit limitation**

and you will get access to the page of interest in this specialized dictionary, best for performing synonym separation

[Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms: A Dictionary of Discriminated](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA501&dq=merriam%20webster%20synonym%20dictionary%20limit%20limitation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mjoYVZKtJfeSsQSShIKYCA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=merriam%20webster%20synonym%20dictionary%20limit%20limitation&f=false)

which tells you that their synonyms are respectively:

---

**limit: bound, end, term**

In the main: a prescribed maximum or minimum amount, quantity, or number

This is more about a **threshold, a boundary, a number**.

---

**limitation: restriction, confinement**

In the main: a restriction or restraint imposed from without (as by law, custom, or circumstances

This is more about a **[constraining] mechanism**.

---

Now, caveat: they are sometimes used as synonyms for each other.

Answer (score 1):

Limitation is the act of setting a limit. "Limit" is sometimes used as a noun, as a synonym for limitation.

Just as "remodel" is often used as a noun, as a synonym for an instance of "remodeling".

Just as "install" is often used as a noun to refer to an instance of "installation".

All of these are, in my opinion, colloquial. I would not use them in written work.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you will be best off following Firth's maxim, *You shall know a word by the company it keeps*. If you have access to a good-sized text corpus you can see in which context each of the two forms are used.

For your perusal, here are the 392 matches for the text string `limit` in the US GPO's online version of the Clean Air Act (including footnotes).

> 1--Section  7386c  related  to  **limits**  on  construction 
>   2--**limitations.** 
>  3--graph  (1)  or  (2)  shall  be  construed 
>   to  **limit**  the  author-
>  4--not  **limited**  to) 
>   consideration  of  the  moisture  con-
>  5--this  title  shall  be 
>   construed  to  **limit**  the  authority  of 
>  6--**limited** to—
>   
>  7--and  subject  to  the  **limitations**  provided  with 
>   8--sions,  including,  but  not  **limited**  to,  auto-
>  9--(a) 
>   Amounts;  **limitations;**  assurances  of  plan  de-
>   10--consideration; State expenditure  **limitations** 
>  11--that 
>   is  chargeable  to  the  percentage  **limitation** 
>  12--ation  to
>   exempting  an  agency  from  the  **limita-**
>  13--Subsec.  (c).
>   Pub. L.  90–148  reduced  percentage  **limita-**
>  14--provisions 
>   **limiting**  available  funds  to  20  per  centum  of 
>  15--the  twelve  and  one-half  percent  **limitation**  of  grant 
>   16--cost  **limitations** 
>  17--reason  of  the  regional 
>   **limitation**  provided  in 
>  18--such  **limitation**  is  due  solely  to  a  redesignation 
>  19--section,  notwithstanding  the 
>   time  **limit**  prescribed  in 
>  20--cluding, but not **limited**
>   to— 
>  21--(vii)  programs  to  **limit**  or  restrict  vehicle
>   
>  22--(ix) programs to **limit** portions of road sur-
>  23--(A) 
>   include  enforceable  emission  **limitations** 
>  24--State  agency
>   with  any  emission  **limitations** 
>  25--section.  The  criteria 
>   shall  be  **limited**  to  the 
>  26--of  emission  **limitations**
>   and  regulation  of  the modifica-
>  27--**limitations**  and 
>   percent  reductions  achieved  in 
>  28--**limitation**  achievable 
>   through  application  of 
>  29--ational  standard;  alternative 
>   emission  **limita-**
>  30--or economic **limitations.** 
>   31--means  of  emission  **limitation**  will  achieve  a  re-
>   32--shall  set  forth emission  **limits** and a compliance 
>   33--that  emission  **limitations**  and  percent  reductions  be-
>   34--under  this  section,  consider  the  emission  **limitations**
>   
>  35--cluding,  but  not  **limited**  to,  substances  which 
>   36--the  preceding  sentence  **limits**  the  Administra-
>   37--techniques  including,  but  not  **limited**  to, 
>   38--**limitation** 
>  39--**limitation** 
>  40--emission 
>   **limitation**  or  other  applicable  re-
>  41--any  standard  or  **limitation**  respecting  emis-
>  42--than the standard or **limitation** in effect under 
>  43--promulgate  emission  **limitations**  under  this 
>  44--trol technology emission **limitation** under this 
>  45--basis  where  no  applicable  emissions  **limita-**
>  46--able  control  technology  emission 
>   **limitation** 
>  47--**limitations**  have  been  established  by  the  Ad-
>  48--nomic **limitations.** 
>  49--that  an  alternative
>   means  of  emission  **limita-**
>  50--standard,  **limitation,** 
>   or  regulation  under  sub-
>  51--such  emission  standard, 
>   regulation  or  **limita-**
>  52--regulation or **limitation.** 
>   53--**limitation**  or  regulation  applicable  to  such 
>   54--**limitation**  or  regulation  is  promulgated  shall 
>   55--(A)  the  promulgated  standard,  **limitation** 
>   56--standard,  **limitation**  or  regulation  proposed; 
>   57--**limitation,**  or  regulation  as  proposed  during 
>   58--standard,  **limitation**  or  regulation  promul-
>   59--violation of  such  standard,  **limitation** or  regu-
>   60--**limitation**  under  this  section  for  a  period  of 
>   61--emission  **limitation**  promulgated  under  sub-
>   62--emission  **limitation**  under  this  paragraph 
>   63--enforceable  emission  **limitation**  for  hazardous 
>   64--sion  **limitation**  under  this  paragraph.  An  al-
>   65--ternative  emission  **limitation**  under  this  para-
>   66--emission  **limitation**  under  this  paragraph  at 
>   67--including,  but  not  **limited**  to,  chlorinated  di-
>   68--regulation  **limit**  the  use  of  offsetting  reduc-
>   69--sions **limitation** under this paragraph. 
>  70--with  the 
>   emission  **limitations**  established 
>  71--such  emission 
>   **limitations**  for  existing  coke 
>  72--emission  **limitations**  shall  reflect  the  lowest 
>  73--**limitations** shall be no less stringent than— 
>  74--rulemaking  in  which  such 
>   emission  **limita-**
>  75--**limitations**  in  terms  of  an 
>   equivalent  level  of 
>  76--such  emission  **limitations**  under 
>   this  subpara-
>  77--sion  **limitations,**  the  emission 
>   **limitations**  ap-
>  78--ministrator  shall  review  the  emission  **limita-**
>  79--revise, as necessary, such emission **limitations** 
>  80--isting battery. Such emission **limitations** shall 
>  81--be  no  less  stringent  than  the  emission 
>   **limita-**
>  82--**limitations**  for  existing  coke  oven  batteries 
>  83--may elect to comply with emission **limitations**
>   
>  84--tion  by  the  date  such  emission  **limitations** 
>   85--tery,  in  lieu  of  the  emission  **limitations**  and 
>   86--comply  with  such  emission  **limitations**  pro-
>   87--January  1,  2003.  If  no  such  emission  **limita-**
>   88--gate  such  emission  **limitations**  in  accordance 
>   89--source  to  emission  **limitations**  under  sub-
>  90--(j)
>   Equivalent emission  **limitation** by permit 
>  91--(5) Emission 
>   **limitation** 
>  92--emission **limitations** for the hazardous air pol-
>  93--emissions  **limitation**  established  according  to
>   
>  94--amounts  exceeding  an  emission  **limitation** 
>   95--plication  is  approved,  the  emission  **limitation** 
>   96--standard  rather  than  the  emission  **limitation** 
>  97--of 
>   the  emission  **limitation**  established  by  per-
>  98--emissions
>   **limitation**  established  by  paragraph 
>  99--not  **limited**  to,  volatile  organic  compounds, 
>  100--shall  include,  but  not
>   be  **limited**  to,  carcino-
>  101--cluding,  but  not 
>   **limited**  to,  the  Toxic  Sub-
>  102--**limited** to, hazardous air pollutants listed pur-
>  103--quirements,  standards,  and 
>   **limitations**  pur-
>  104--uct  substitutions  or  **limitations**  that  may  be 
>  105--be **limited** to, the following— 
>   106--ing,  but  not  **limited**  to,  inheritable  genetic 
>   107--trator  shall  use,  but  is  not  **limited**  to,  the  list
>   
>  108--nation of  functions and to  **limit** duplication of 
>   109--Administration  so  as  to  **limit**  duplication  of 
>   110--shall  include,  but  not  be  **limited**  to,  informa-
>   111--cluding,  but  not  **limited**  to,  the  size,  location, 
>   112--deny  or  **limit**  any  right  of  a  State  or  political 
>   113--regulation,  requirement,  **limitation**  or  stand-
>   114--quirement,  **limitation**  or  standard  in  effect 
>   115--include, but not be **limited** to— 
>  116--U.S.C.  7412(o)], 
>   the use  and  **limitations**  of  risk  assess-
>  117--emissions 
>   standards  and  other  **limitations**  applicable 
>   118--including, but not **limited** to, a requirement or 
>   119--fect  or  **limit**  the  State’s  or  the  United  States 
>   120--**limited** to, a requirement or prohibition of any 
>   121--including, but not **limited** to, a requirement or 
>   122--graph  shall  be  **limited**  to  matters  where  the 
>   123--ment  expenses,  including  but  not  **limited**  to  at-
>   124--shall  in  no  way  **limit**  the  Administrator’s  au-
>   125--**limitation**  or  other  requirement  which  is  adopt-
>   126--respect to such standard, **limitation,** or other re-
>   127--standard  or  **limitation**  respecting  emissions  of 
>   128--that  if  an  emission  standard  or  **limitation**  is  in 
>   129--or **limitation** under such plan or section. 
>  130--vided, 
>   emission  standards  or  **limitations**  under  the 
>   131--**limited**  to,  persons  who  are  knowledgeable  con-
>   132--order  is  issued  is  an  emission  **limitation**  or 
>   133--progress  shall  be  **limited**  to  requiring  compli-
>   134--sion  **limitation**  as  expeditiously  as  practicable 
>   135--compliance  with  any  emission  **limitation,** 
>   136--pliance  with  an  emission  **limitation,**  emission 
>   137--(g)  More  stringent  emission  **limitations**  or  other 
>   138--In the case of any emission **limitation** or other 
>   139--sion  **limitation**  or  requirement  for  the  source  in 
>   140--any,  or  where  there  was  no  emission  **limitation** 
>   141--such emission **limitation** or requirement, which-
>   142--emission **limitation** or requirement. 
>  143--emission 
>   **limitations,**  standards  of  performance, 
>  144--(3)  In  case  of  any  standard  or  emission  **limita-**
>  145--tion  of  such 
>   standard  or  **limitation**  to  a  source 
>  146--such  standard 
>   or  **limitation**  shall  not  apply  to 
>  147--The  degree  of 
>   emission  **limitation**  required  for 
>  148--emission 
>   **limitation**  for coal-fired  steam electric 
>  149--tional means of emission  **limitation** which  the 
>  150--**limitations**  and 
>   compliance  schedules  (contain-
>  151--emissions  **limitations** 
>   and  other  requirements 
>  152--gent  than  the  average  emissions
>   **limitation** 
>  153--(4) Numerical emissions  **limitations** 
>  154--units  shall  specify  numerical  emission  **limita-**
>   155--gate  numerical  emissions  **limitations**  or  pro-
>   156--sions  **limitations,**  notwithstanding  any  re-
>  157--ing 
>   issuance  of  such  **limitations),**  subsection 
>   158--**limitations** or implement any other measures, if 
>   159--emissions  in  the  absence  of  such  **limitations**  or 
>   160--standard,  emission  **limitation**  or  other  re-
>   161--standard,  **limitation** or  requirement applies  to 
>   162--operate  such  unit  in  violation  of  such  **limita-**
>   163--each  performance  standard,  emission  **limita-**
>   164--emission **limitation.** 
>  165--opacity  **limitations**  to 
>   be  established  by  the 
>  166--lation, requirement, **limitation**
>   or standard re-
>  167--ment,  **limitation**  or  standard  in 
>   effect  under 
>  168--tation  plan  shall  contain  emission 
>   **limitations** 
>  169--ting  forth  emission  **limitations**  for  such  facil-
>  170--variance; emission  **limitations** 
>   171--emission  **limitations**  under  such  permit  as  may 
>   172--with  such  emission  **limitations**  under  such  per-
>   173--nology’’  means  an  emission  **limitation**  based 
>   174--such  emission  **limits,**  schedules  of  compliance 
>   175--in  excess  of  750 megawatts,  the  emission  **limita-**
>   176--determining  emission  **limitations**  which  re-
>   177--**limits,** schedules of compliance, and other meas-
>  178--(A)
>   the most stringent emission **limitation** 
>  179--**limitations**
>   are not achievable, or 
>  180--(B) the most stringent emission 
>   **limitation** 
>  181--able  emission  **limitations,** and  such other  con-
>  182--sources  to  meet  emission  **limitations**  at 
>   least  as 
>  183--be within the **limitations** set forth in such
>   construction 
>  184--emission **limitations** and are in compliance,
>   or 
>  185--ble  emission  **limitations**  and  standards  under
>   
>  186--**limited**  to,  authority  exercised  under  chapter  53
>   
>  187--any  such  State  to  prohibit  or  **limit,**  directly  or
>   
>  188--ing  States  from  **limiting**  or  prohibiting  sale  or 
>   manu-
>  189--(vi)  programs  to  **limit**  or  restrict  vehicle
>   
>  190--not  be  **limited**  to,  the  collection  of 
>   meteorological 
>  191--ation  measures  may  include,  but  not  be 
>   **limited**  to 
>  192--from, but not  **limited** to, section  7408(f) of this 
>  193--may **limit** the application of paragraph
>   (1) to the 
>  194--tions,  **limitations,**  or  economic 
>   incentives  (in-
>  195--shall  take  into  consideration  **limits**
>   on  fill  pipe 
>  196--tainer  lips,  **limits**  on  the  location 
>   of  the  un-
>  197--quirements,  and  **limitations**  applicable 
>   to  it 
>  198--subsection shall not affect or **limit** the
>   Admin-
>  199--1970—Pub.  L.  91–604  increased  the  upper 
>   **limit**  of  the 
>  200--(I)  **limit**  or  otherwise  affect  the  application 
>  201--(IV) Subclause  (I) shall not  **limit**
>   the Adminis-
>  202--graph  (1)  or  (3)  of  this  subsection  or 
>   the  **limita-**
>  203--Reid vapor pressure  **limitation** under 
>   this  sub-
>  204--pressure  **limitations**  established  under 
>   para-
>  205--plies  with  the  Reid  vapor  pressure 
>   **limita-**
>  206--the  Reid  vapor  pressure  **limitation**  estab-
>  207--sure  **limitation**  established  by  paragraph  (1)
>   
>  208--with the **limitation** on emissions of oxides of 
>   209--supplies  of  oxygenated  gasoline  are  **limited,** 
>   210--such  provisions,  including  **limiting**  the  cred-
>   211--renewable  fuel  producers,  and  to  **limit**  any 
>   212--**limit** the number of cellulosic biofuel credits 
>   213--Clause (i) does not **limit** the authority of 
>  214--or  to 
>   expand  or  **limit**  regulatory  authority  re-
>  215--this 
>   section  and  subject  to  the  **limitations**  in 
>  216--(A)
>   Frequency  **limitation** 
>  217--subsection  or  the 
>   **limitation**  specified  in  paragraph  (2) 
>  218--cluding,  but  not  **limited**  to,  carcinogenic,  teratogenic, 
>   219--refinery’’  and  which  **limited**  Administrator’s  authority
>   
>  220--sion  relating  to  applicability  of  **limitation** 
>   specified 
>  221--superseding,  or  **limiting,**  any  more 
>   environmentally 
>  222--chanical  problems  (including  but  not 
>   **limited**  to  valve 
>  223--**limiting**  lead  content  of  gasoline  would  be  appropriate 
>  224--but not  **limited** to
>   tire debris, and asbestos  from 
>  225--to  **limit**  the 
>   Administrator’s  authority  to  re-
>  226--for testing (including,
>   but not **limited** to, certifi-
>  227--may  adjust  for  a 
>   **limited**  period  the  deadlines 
>  228--(2)  Use  of  credits;  **limitations**  based  on  weight 
>  229--in this paragraph shall **limit** the applicability of 
>  230--calculation  with  respect  to  a  **limitation**  under 
>  231--includes,  but  is  not 
>   **limited**  to,  effects  on  soils, 
>  232--(k)  The  terms  ‘‘emission  **limitation’’**  and 
>  233--**limits**  the  quantity,
>   rate,  or  concentration  of 
>  234--(m)  The  term  ‘‘means  of 
>   emission  **limitation’’** 
>  235--sion **limitation,** other
>   **limitation,** prohibition, or 
>  236--which  includes  enforceable  emission  **limitations** 
>  237--of  (A)  an  emission  standard 
>   or  **limitation** 
>  238--such a standard or **limitation,** 
>   239--emission  standard  or  **limitation,**  or  such  an 
>   240--lator of the standard, **limitation,** or order, or 
>   241--ard,  **limitation,** or order, but  in any such ac-
>   242--**limitation**  may  be  brought  only  in  the  judicial 
>   243--forcement  of  any  emission  standard  or  **limita-**
>   244--(f)  ‘‘Emission  standard  or  **limitation**  under  this 
>   245--sion  standard  or  **limitation**  under  this  chapter’’ 
>   246--emission  **limitation,**  standard  of  performance 
>   247--(4)  any  other  standard,  **limitation,**  or  sched-
>   248--not  **limited**  to  section  7413,  section  7414,  section
>   
>  249--this  title,  or  emission  standard  or  **limitation**
>   
>  250--thority,  or  **limitations,**  or  short  of  statutory
>   
>  251--**limitation** to so comply, and 
>  252--superseding  or 
>   **limiting**  the  authorities  and  re-
>  253--(4)  a  **limitation**  under  this  chapter  for  emis-
>  254--(5)  a  **limitation**  under  subchapter  VI  of  this 
>  255--but  not  **limited**  to,  injunctive  relief,  compen-
>  256--standards  or  **limitations**  contained  in  a  State 
>  257--but  not  be  **limited**  to, State  and  local  require-
>  258--ments  for  emission  controls,  emission  **limita-**
>  259--Such  activities 
>   include,  but  are  not  **limited** 
>  260--scribed  emission 
>   **limitations**  by  specified  dead-
>  261--lines, which  **limitations** may be met  through al-
>  262--ments or **limitations** under this subchapter. 
>  263--**limitation** for sulfur dioxide or oxides of nitro-
>  264--such  a  **limitation** 
>   for  1985  does  not  exist. 
>  265--Where  the  emissions 
>   **limitation**  for  a  unit  is 
>  266--sions  **limitation**  is  not  expressed  on  an  annual 
>  267--annual equivalent of that
>   emissions **limitation** 
>  268--(1) 1 For  the  emission 
>   **limitation**  programs 
>  269--nual  tonnage  emission  **limitation**  calculated 
>  270--to  the emissions  **limitation**  requirements of  sec-
>  271--emission  **limitation**  requirement 
>   compliance 
>  272--**limited**  to,  requirements  for  the 
>   allocation, 
>  273--which  are  applied  to  emissions 
>   **limitations**  re-
>  274--is a  **limited** authorization  to emit  sulfur dioxide 
>  275--**limit**  the  authority  of  the  United 
>   States  to  ter-
>  276--minate  or  **limit**  such  authorization. 
>   Nothing  in 
>  277--regulation  or  as  **limiting**  State 
>   regulation  (in-
>  278--shall  supersede  any  other  emission 
>   **limitation** 
>  279--(a) Emission  **limitations** 
>  280--sulfur  dioxide  in  excess  of  the  tonnage  **limita-**
>   281--that, after January 1, 2000, the emissions **limita-**
>   282--such  violation  including,  but  not  **limited**  to,  li-
>   283--emissions  **limitation**  requirements  of  this  sec-
>   284--ject  to  the emissions  **limitation**  requirements of 
>   285--units  subject  to  the  emissions  **limitations**  of 
>   286--(4)  the  emissions  rates  and  tonnage  **limita-**
>   287--**limits**  will,  in  total,  achieve  the  same  or 
>   288--**limitation**  provided  for  in  the  approved  substi-
>   289--subject  to  an  emissions  **limitation**  requirement 
>   290--(E) specify the emission **limitation** and num-
>   291--**limitations**  provided  for  in  the  permit  and  ap-
>   292--nual  tonnage  **limitation**  specified  in  the  exten-
>   293--sions **limitation** requirements of section 7651d of 
>   294--**limitation**  requirements  of  this  section  which 
>   295--unit  as  provided  below  is  subject  to  the  **limita-**
>   296--nage  emission  **limitation**  under  this  section  is 
>   297--shall  not  be  subject  to  the  8,900,000  ton  **limita-**
>   298--**limitation**  equal  to  the  product  of  the  unit’s 
>   299--for each unit subject to the emissions **limitation** 
>   300--fur dioxide tonnage **limitation** equal to the prod-
>   301--the  emissions  **limitation**  requirements  of  para-
>   302--ceed  an  annual  sulfur  dioxide  emissions  **limita-**
>   303--ide  tonnage  emissions  **limitation**  equal  to  the 
>   304--annual  sulfur  dioxide  emissions  tonnage  **limita-**
>   305--unit subject to the emissions **limitation** require-
>   306--emissions  tonnage  **limitation**  equal  to  the  prod-
>   307--**limitation** requirements of paragraph (1) with an 
>   308--annual  sulfur  dioxide  emissions  tonnage  **limita-**
>   309--emissions  **limitation**  requirements  of  this  para-
>   310--**limitation**  equal  to  the  product  of  its  baseline 
>   311--**limitation**  equal  to  the  product  of  the  unit’s 
>   312--**limitation**  equal  to  the  product  of  the  unit’s 
>   313--ject  to  the emissions  **limitation**  requirements of 
>   314--ject  to  the emissions  **limitation**  requirements of 
>   315--to the emissions  **limitation** requirements of this 
>   316--**limitation**  requirements  of  this  subsection.  The 
>   317--a  unit  subject  to  the  emissions  **limitation**  re-
>   318--nage  **limitation**  equal  to  the  product  of  the 
>   319--annual  sulfur  dioxide  tonnage  emissions  **limita-**
>   320--an  annual  tonnage  emission  **limitation**  equal  to 
>   321--annual  sulfur  dioxide  tonnage  emissions  **limita-**
>   322--nual  sulfur  dioxide  tonnage  **limitation**  equal  to 
>   323--for each unit subject to the emissions **limitation** 
>   324--subject  to  the  emissions  **limitation**  require-
>   325--ject  to  an  emissions  **limitation**  requirement 
>   326--**limitation**  requirements  of  this  section  applica-
>   327--**limitation**  requirements  of  this  section:  Pro-
>   328--emissions  **limitation**  requirements  of  subsection 
>   329--**limitation**  requirements  of  subsection  (b)(1)  of 
>   330--the  unit  pursuant  to  the  emissions  **limitation** 
>   331--tion and shall be subject to the emission  **limita-**
>   332--(b) Emission  **limitations** 
>  333--ity  boilers  listed 
>   below,  which  **limitations**  shall 
>  334--emission 
>   **limitations**  on  a  lb/mmBtu,  annual  av-
>  335--vise  the applicable  emission  **limitations**  for  tan-
>  336--emission
>   **limitations,** if any. 
>  337--(d) Alternative emission  **limitations** 
>  338--section,  authorize  an  emission  **limitation**  less 
>  339--stringent  than  the  applicable  **limitation**  estab-
>  340--section  cannot  meet  the  applicable  **limitation** 
>  341--based the applicable emission **limitation.** 
>  342--for  which  an  alternative  emission  **limitation**  is
>   
>  343--ble  of  achieving  the  applicable  emission 
>   **limita-**
>  344--to the emissions **limitation** requirements of sub-
>  345--sion  **limitations**  under  subsection  (b)(1),  (2), 
>   or 
>  346--plicable  emission  **limitations**  set  pursuant  to
>   
>  347--emission  **limitations**  for  such  units  that  ensure
>   
>  348--of  time,  in  compliance  with  **limitations**  set  in
>   
>  349--tations. Such emission **limitations** shall only re-
>   350--tors,  of  a  unit  subject  to  the  emissions  **limita-**
>   351--plicable  emissions  **limitation**  requirements  of 
>   352--case of the emissions **limitation** requirements of 
>   353--**limitation**  equal  to  the  product  of  the  unit’s 
>   354--(f) Units subject  to certain other  **limits** 
>  355--sions
>   **limitation** requirements of section 7651d(b) 
>  356--be  granted  an  extension  of  the  emission  **limita-**
>  357--**limitations**
>   and  is  economically  or  techno-
>  358--tion  Plan  emissions 
>   **limitation**  or  its  actual 
>  359--emissions  **limitation**  requirement  set  forth  in 
>  360--(c) Emission  **limitations**
>   
>  361--Annual  emissions  **limitations**  for  sulfur  diox-
>   362--designated;  specify  the  emissions  **limitation;** 
>   363--equal  to  the  emissions  **limitation**  calculated 
>   364--emissions **limitation** requirement or, in the case 
>   365--ted  in  excess  of  the  unit’s  emissions  **limitation** 
>   366--year  in excess of  the unit’s emissions  **limitation** 
>   367--Nothing  in  this  subchapter  shall  **limit**  or 
>   368--regulations  may  include  **limitations**  or  the  use 
>   369--cluding,  but  not  **limited**  to,  units  that  become 
>   370--sion **limitation,** or emission prohibition. 
>  371--permits 
>   incorporate  emission  **limitations** 
>  372--should be construed
>   to **limit** the Administrator’s 
>  373--shall  include  enforceable
>   emission  **limitations** 
>  374--locations, including, but not
>   **limited** to, ambient 
>  375--not  **limited**  to,  accidental  and  intentional  releases 
>  376--**limited**  to,  accidental  and
>   intentional  releases  from 
>  377--thorize  the production of 
>   **limited** quantities of 
>  378--**limited**  quantities  of  class  I  substances  solely 
>  379--**limited**  quantities  of 
>   halon-1211 
>  380--**limited** quantities of a class  I  substance 
>   in ex-
>  381--**limited**  quantities  of  methyl  bromide,  solely
>   
>  382--thorize  the  production  of  **limited**  quantities  of
>   
>  383--ize  the  production  of  **limited**  quantities  of 
>   384--use  of  **limited**  quantities  of  class  II  sub-
>   385--tion  of  **limited**  quantities  of  a  class  II  sub-
>   386--tablishes  revised  production  **limits**  for  the 
>   387--under  the  revised production  **limits**  equals  the 
>   388--production  **limits**  in  the  same  manner  as  pro-
>   389--(b) Effect of  transfers on production  **limits** 
>   390--production  **limits** established under this chapter 
>   391--to  increase  production  **limits**  established  under 
>   392--from **limited** experiences.